# How can I build and stream a zip/tar archive file by file to the client?

Tags: python, wsgi, zip

I understand that it's possible to build zip/tar archives "dynamically" when sending them to the browser; one sends the headers then compresses each file and streams those parts to the browser, which can aid in building large archives when server memory is limited.

Is this achievable over WSGI?

Comment: Besides initial mis-information-fueled-now-deleted-wrong-answer, there is an actual reason: most WSGI servers don't deal with streaming responses *at all*. Middleware generally read in the full response, for example, before passing it on to their upstream client, so I fear this is not going to work.

Comment: I would suggest using a front-end cache like varnish. You pay the cost of generating the zip the first time, but subsequent downloads will be streamable and fast.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As far as I'm aware, WSGI is designed to stream. It's part of [PEP-0333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#buffering-and-streaming), specifically: `WSGI servers, gateways, and middleware must not delay the transmission of any block; they must either fully transmit the block to the client, or guarantee that they will continue transmission even while the application is producing its next block` which is how one returns a file - reading and yielding a chunk to the next layer. Unless I'm misunderstanding the spec.

Comment: I see two questions: 1. building a big zip file dynamically and effective (are the same zipped components of zip repated for many different requested zip files?); 2. Is it easy to use that part of PEP-0333 well? read [[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/modwsgi/jr2ayp0xesk]] [[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811404/wsgi-file-streaming-with-a-generator]]

Comment: @jterrace unfortunately this isn't possible, as the downloads are *dynamic*; the items that are in the zip will be chosen by the user and the chance of two users picking the same items are slim.

Comment: When you say "achievable over WSGI", are you asking if a WSGI app is capable of doing it, or if WSGI has some special capability to make it simpler?

Answer (score 0):

In Werkzeug at least, the [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse) says

> Response can be any kind of iterable or string. If it’s a string it’s
>   considered being an iterable with one item which is the string passed.

so if you can build a generator or some other kind of iterator to serve up the data in chunks, it will get concatenated together and served as one file. (Note: you'll probably also want to pass the `direct_passthrough` flag to the Response object to do it through Werkzeug.)

If you can't use Werkzeug, you can probably get started by investigating how Werkzeug does it.

Answer (score 0):

I see another similar question in [Create and stream a large archive without storing it in memory or on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405210/create-and-stream-a-large-archive-without-storing-it-in-memory-or-on-disk) ,the questioner turn to https://github.com/SpiderOak/ZipStream at last