# Streaming data of unknown size from client to server over HTTP in Python

Tags: python, http, upload

As unfortunately my previous question got closed for being an "exact copy" of a question while it definitely IS NOT, hereby again.

It is NOT a duplicate of [Python: HTTP Post a large file with streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502596/python-http-post-a-large-file-with-streaming)

That one deals with streaming a big file; I want to send arbitrary chunks of a file one by one to the same http connection. So I have a file of say 20 MB, and what I want to do is open an HTTP connection, then send 1 MB, send another 1 MB, etc, until it's complete. Using the same connection, so the server sees a 20 MB chunk appear over that connection.

Mmapping a file is what I ALSO intend to do, but that does not work when the data is read from stdin. And primarily for that second case I an looking for this part-by-part feeding of data.

Honestly I wonder whether it can be done at all - if not, I'd like to know, then can close the issue. But if it can be done, how could it be done?

Comment: Is the only different behavior you seek is scrambling the file?

Comment: *I want to send arbitrary chunks of a file one by one to the same http connection.* That is called streaming. *(...) but that does not work when the data is read from stdin*. In this case your question is misleading as it mentions **file** explicitly which means the size of input data is known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the client’s perspective, it’s easy. You can use [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)’s low-level interface—[`putrequest`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.putrequest), [`putheader`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.putheader), [`endheaders`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.endheaders), and [`send`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.send)—to send whatever you want to the server in chunks of any size.

But you also need to indicate where your file ends.

If you know the total size of the file in advance, you can simply include the `Content-Length` header, and the server will stop reading your request body after that many bytes. The code may then look like this.

```
import httplib
import os.path

total_size = os.path.getsize('/path/to/file')
infile = open('/path/to/file')
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('example.org')
conn.connect()
conn.putrequest('POST', '/upload/')
conn.putheader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
conn.putheader('Content-Length', str(total_size))
conn.endheaders()
while True:
    chunk = infile.read(1024)
    if not chunk:
        break
    conn.send(chunk)
resp = conn.getresponse()
```

If you don’t know the total size in advance, the theoretical answer is the [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Problem is, while it is widely used for responses, it seems less popular (although just as well defined) for requests. Stock HTTP servers may not be able to handle it out of the box. But if the server is under your control too, you could try manually parsing the chunks from the request body and reassembling them into the original file.

Another option is to send each chunk as a separate request (with `Content-Length`) over the same connection. But you still need to implement custom logic on the server. Moreover, you need to persist state between requests.

**Added 2012-12-27.** There’s [an nginx module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpChunkinModule) that converts chunked requests into regular ones. May be helpful so long as you don’t need true streaming (start handling the request before the client is done sending it).

Comment: Excellent, looks just like what I needed. Will work on it, probably can accept this answer. Total size is often not known - in case we get the file piped in over stdin (which is where mmap just doesn't work), but I think will be able to work around that somehow.