# How to send huge files over HTTPPost method in Python, upload large files

Tags: python, http, post, file-upload, streaming

I am tring to post huge .ova file through HTTPPost Method in Python

```
**ResponseHeaders**
Pragma  no-cache
Date    Thu, 18 Jul 2013 11:17:13 GMT
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
**RequestHeaders**
Content-Type    application/json
Accept  application/json
xyzAPIVersion   1.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

How to send such a huge file(500 MB) through HTTPPost method through REST API.

Comment: related: [Python: HTTP Post a large file with streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2502596/4279)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads):

```
import requests # $ pip install requests

with open("file.ova", "rb") as file:
    requests.post(url, data=file)
```