# How to stream a file in a request?

Tags: python, django, stream, python-requests

We have a `react` application communicating with a django backend. Whenever the `react` application wants to upload a file to the backend, we send a form request with one field being the handle of the file being upload. The field is received on the Django side as an 
`InMemoryUploadedFile`, which is an object with some `chunks`, which can be processed for example like this:

```
def save_uploaded_file(uploaded_file, handle):
    """
    Saves the uploaded file using the given file handle.
    We walk the chunks to avoid reading the whole file in memory
    """
    for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
        handle.write(chunk)
    handle.flush()
    logger.debug(f'Saved file {uploaded_file.name} with length {uploaded_file.size}')
```

Now, I am creating some testing framework using `requests` to drive our API. I am trying to emulate this mechanism, but strangely enough, `requests` insists on reading from the open handle before sending the request. I am doing:

```
requests.post(url, data, headers=headers, **kwargs)
```

with:

```
data = {'content': open('myfile', 'rb'), ...}
```

Note that I am not reading from the file, I am just opening it. But requests insists on reading from it, and sends the data embedded, which has several problems:

- it can be huge
- by being binary data, it corrupts the request
- it is not what my application expects

I do not want this: I want `requests` simply to "stream" that file, not to read it. There is a files parameter, but that will create a multipart with the file embedded in the request, which is again not what I want. I want all fields in the data to be passed in the request, and the content field to be streamed. I know this is possible because:

- the browser does it
- Postman does it
- the django test client does it

How can I force requests to stream a particular file in the data?

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217788/7505395

Comment: and this might be a dupe: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502596/python-http-post-a-large-file-with-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502596/python-http-post-a-large-file-with-streaming) - if so please dupeclose it yourself :) If I close it (and I am not sure) it gets dupe-hammered

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks, but not the same. Those are talking either about non-requests solutions, or using the full data paratemer as the file to be streamed. My problem is different: the data parameter has several fields, and *one* of them is a file to be streamed. If I try this with `requests`, the file gets read. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this is no longer relevant, but I will share some information that I found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).

> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django
> will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. This means that
> saving the file involves only a read from memory and a write to disk
> and thus is very fast. However, if an uploaded file is too large,
> Django will write the uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your
> system’s temporary directory.

This way, there is no need to create a streaming file upload. Rather, the solution might be to handle (read) the loaded using a buffer.